# Error al intentar ingresar

Tags: php, php7

El error que tengo actualmente es qué al parecer mi código no percata que tipo de usuario (rol) está ingresando. estoy usando en mi base de datos estos siguientes roles:

1 - Administrador
2 - Rector
3 - Coordinador
4 - Profesor
5 - Acudiente
6 - Estudiante

Cabo recalcar lo que sucede. No aparece ningún tipo de error, pero siempre te manda al panel de estudiantes, aún así poniendo bien la contraseña e iniciar sesión de forma correcta, pero otra incógnita es que sí inicio sesión de forma incorrecta, aún así me sigue mandando al panel de estudiante y no se esta ejecutando la función else de mi if.

Acá está mi código:

````
session_start();
include('Conexión.php');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$Iniciador=$_POST['Verificar'];
if(isset($Iniciador)){
    $user=$_POST['Identificación'];
    $pass=$_POST['Constraseña'];

    $sql="SELECT Id_Usuario, Clave_Usuario, Tipo_Usuario, concat(Nombres_Usuario,' ',Apellidos_Usuario) from usuario where Id_Usuario='$user' and Clave_Usuario='$pass'";
    $Respuesta=$Conexion->query($sql);
    $fila=$Respuesta->fetch_row();
    
    if($fila[0]==$user && $fila[1]==$pass){
        $_SESSION['Identificación']=$fila[0];
        $_SESSION['Tipo']=$fila[2];
        $_SESSION['Nombre']=$fila[3];
        $msj="Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['Nombre']."";
            switch ($_SESSION['Tipo']) {
                case '1':
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Administrador/Index.php');
                    break;
                case '2':
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Rector/Index.php');
                    break;
                case '3':
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Coordinador/Index.php');
                    break;
                case '4':
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Profesor/Index.php');
                    break;
                case '5':
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Acudiente/Index.php');
                    break;
                case '6':
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Estudiante/Index.php');
                    break;
                default:
                    header('location:../Vista/App/Roles/Estudiante/Index.php');
                    break;
            }
    } else{
        echo "<script>
                    alert('¡Usuario incorrecto!');
                    location.href='../Vista/Publico/Archivos/Páginas/Logueo.php';
                    </script>";
    }
}
?>```
````

Comment: intenta hacer un `var_dump($fila);` para ver el contenido que te está trayendo el fetch de la query

Comment: Como tu default envía a la página de estudiantes se puede concluir que en todos los casos la consulta está fallando y nunca devuelve el valor que esperas. Por otra parte el diseño admite toda clase de ataques (particularmente inyección sql). Es posible que la conexión no se haya creado (en el código no se ve que la crees antes de ejecutar la consulta). **¿Verificaste en alguna parte que hubiese conexión a la Base de datos?**

Comment: Hola. Estoy haciendo un include aparte llamado Conexión.php, este es el código.                                                                                                             <?php 
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$db="academysoftware";
$pass="";
$msj="¡No se pudo encontrar la base de datos!";

$Conexion= new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$db) or die ($msj);
$Acento= $Conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo 'Conexión fallida: ', mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
?>

Comment: Aparte de lo ya dicho por otros compañeros, faltan algunas verificaciones: ¿qué te asegura que los criterios esenciales para la consulta (`$user` y `$pass`) no están vacíos? ¿Qué te asegura que la consulta no ha fallado (algo mal escrito, problemas de codificación –por cierto, evita el uso de `ñ` y de acentos en variables y nombres de tablas/columnas, pues si no controlas la codificación producirán errores–). Hay también un problema de seguridad al no guardar las claves hasheadas. Sea como sea, si haces un control estricto del código encontrarás el error.

Comment: Hola, aún soy estudiante y no llevo más de 3 semanas usando php, soy nuevo en esto, gracias por tus sugerencias respecto al uso de caracteres especiales.